# what exactly is the actual image data inside IDAT chunck in PNG file?

Tags: algorithm, compression, png

PNG Specification [here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html) says PNG file contains a chunk IDAT which contains the actual image data.

My question is when I modify (using hex editor) LSB of any 1 byte in IDAT the whole image goes bad(colors changes randomly or image becomes transparent with some outline remaining or completely blank).

How just changing 1 byte can cause this?

Comment: There is a checksum across each chunk.

Comment: but I am changing only 1 byte in 1 chunk out of multiple chunks. Then why whole image is being affected.

Comment: It's compressed data. Any error propagates through the rest of the data. Whatever is reading the PNG image should be rejecting it as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It says exactly what's in there in the specification you linked. Did you consider reading the specification?